# How do you change the color of title of table generated with DT library in shiny app?

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt, bs4dash

I am rendering a table in my shiny app. Table is generated with DT library.
This is the code:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({# Displaying table in section tab for principal and director
    if (user_logged$Designation=='director'|user_logged$Designation=='principal'){
    data <- teacher_info[teacher_info$Section == input$sections,]
    data <- data%>%
      select(-c(Section))
    }
```

This is the output:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3E1U.png)
As you can see due to background color, column title and other title becomes obscure. I want to change the color of those texts and if possible I also want to change background color of table.

Answer (score 0):

I think yours is a similar question to the one here [How to change shiny app dataTableOutput font color and auxiliary table element color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318401/how-to-change-shiny-app-datatableoutput-font-color-and-auxiliary-table-element-c)

you can add

```
tags$style(HTML(
".dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    }"))
```

as inline CSS to your ui, the link also shows how to change the page numbers if relevant