# How to change shiny app dataTableOutput font color for a specific table when there are multiple tables on the page?

Tags: r, datatables

I'm following the example for changing dataTable font colors from this answer: [How to change shiny app dataTableOutput font color and auxiliary table element color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318401/how-to-change-shiny-app-datatableoutput-font-color-and-auxiliary-table-element-c)

However, I have multiple tables on the same page, and that code affects every table on the page, even if it isn't specified until the final table (which makes sense given that it's css and applies to all the matching elements).

How can I specifically target an individual table?  I see that the tables have ID's when I use Selector Gadget, starting from 1 through n in order of appearance (this order won't change, so it can be hardcoded), but I have been unable to find how to specify the css for a specific, individual table.